# What are the more important effects or consequences of gamma-ray bursts for the cosmos?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, cosmology, astrophysics, gamma-rays

I would like to know what are, in general, the consequences/effects of the known gamma-ray bursts. I refer gamma-ray bursts from the Wikipedia [*Gamma-ray burst*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma-ray_burst#Classification) that shows how are classified and the other relevant sections for my question. I'm going to exclude for our discussion the effects on life, and I'm not interested in the effects on a planet similar than our planet Earth (this information is in the linked Wikipedia).

To emphasize my question I know from an informative point of view that physicists sometimes are experimenting models programmed with the help of a computer: they study for example what if remove the dark-matter from the simulation, what if certain physical constant is modified by a small quantity,...
They also do thought experiments (Gedankenexperiment). An obvious example, if I remove certain type of stars from a good simulation of our universe/cosmos, then the synthesis of certain chemical elements could be impossible.

> **Question.** What are the more important/relevant effects or consequences (we aren't interested neither effects on life nor effects on bodies as the planets) of gamma-ray bursts for the cosmos? **Many thanks.**

With the word *cosmos* I refer in some way a *Theory of Everything*: I'm asking from the ignorance with cosmos the structure of matter, the known or hypothesized particles, interactions and/or dimensions, cosmos is also the black-holes, the structure of space-time, and the structure of the universe if maybe is infinite or what is its form, quantum fields or wave-function of things, etc... This is everything which can be explained with physical theories and reasonings.

I'm asking **what work can be done about it**, I don't know if it is possible to evoke a feasible and concise answer. If this question is in the literature feel free to answer this post as a reference request and I try to read and understand the articles from the literature.

### References:

As reference (the only that I know) from this Physics Stack Exchange (Jul 28 '15) is the post [*Do gamma ray bursts play a role in cosmic evolution?*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/196339/do-gamma-ray-bursts-play-a-role-in-cosmic-evolution)

Comment: As reference (the only that I know) from this Physics Stack Exchange (Jul 28 '15) is the post *Do gamma ray bursts play a role in cosmic evolution?* with identificator **196339**

Comment: To emphasize my question of this post **I'm asking what work can be done** to elucidate the more important or relevant effects of the gamma-ray bursts for the cosmos. I evoke references or a concise summary of those effects from your knowledges, before I'm accepting an answer. On the other hand please feel free to add your feedback about my post in comments, and it is appreciated if you or some of your colleagues visit my other unanswered question on this site Physics Stack Exchange.